# How to do validation select option using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, validation

I have the following select options. Data is coming dynamically from web service.

```
<select ng-model="sub_class_name" name="sub_class_name" class="form-control">                                                                   
<option ng-repeat="x in myData" value="{{x}}">{{x.sub_class_name}}</option>
</select>
```

[image]

I want to validate when no value is chosen. I have a separate js file in which am doing validation for text box. But not working in case of select option..

I has been doing validation like this. But how to do for select option.?

```
rules: {
    FirstName: {
      required: !0
    },
    sub_class_name: {
      required: !0 // Not working
    }
},
```

Comment: why don't use angular validation?

Comment: Am using bootstrap form wizard...

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute required for select option if you do have an option without value or blank like this -

```
<select ng-model="sub_class_name" name="sub_class_name" class="form-control" required>                                                   
        <option ng-repeat="x in myData" value="{{x}}">{{x.sub_class_name}}</option>
</select>
```

or:

```
    rules: {
     sub_class_name: { valueNotEquals: "default" }
    },
    messages: {
     SelectName: { valueNotEquals: "Please select a class!" }
    }
```

Where valueNotEquals should be either blank or default or please select a class... etc..

Comment: Not working...... Since am using form wizard at first step I dnt have submit... I have three steps...

Comment: Run validation function on click of next button.

Answer (score 0):

Add option like this...

```
<select ng-model="classname" name="classname" class="form-control" ng-options="t as t.class_name for t in MemberClass">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

In your JQuery do validation normally..

```
classname: {
 required: !0
},
sub_class_name: {
required: !0
},
```